# Second partial derivatives of harmonic functions

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative, harmonic-functions

Given a twice-differentiable function $f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $S$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, how does one prove that if f is harmonic then the second partials $D_jD_kf$ all vanish at $(x,y) = (x_0,y_0)$, where $x_0$ and $y_0$ are some local minima or maxima of $f$ in $S$?

Comment: ????? If $f$ is harmonic then has no local extrema: http://books.google.es/books?id=PJeHprppOLsC&pg=PA248&lpg=PA248&dq=%22harmonic+function%22+%22local+minimum%22&source=bl&ots=yEwVIb4goQ&sig=g39f8l4ZdJWTvyqg97K3WwWuZ-w&hl=es&sa=X&ei=ajo1U5jPBOqN0AX9m4CADg&ved=0CG0Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22harmonic%20function%22%20%22local%20minimum%22&f=false.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: Yes, so it vanishes........

Comment: @John: in the sense that is vacuously true?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: If it has local extrema, then $f$ is constant....

Comment: @John: are you interpreting that the question is "prove that a nonconstant harmonic function has no local extrema using that..."?

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: The question itself is kind of strange right? One can apply maximum principle to say that $f$ is constant (as it has a local extrema), so in particular all second derivative vanishes.

Comment: @John: a tricky question with easy answer if you *know* the basic facts?